# Regex to remove "=\r"

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's the text I have:

```
[ '
  "message": "WorldStage Supports Massive 4K Video Mapping at Adobe MAX=\r
 with Christie Boxer 4K Projectors',
  '
   "message": "Inside Track: Trading Focus on Shares of Adobe Systems In=\r
c. (ADBE)' ]
```

I want it to look like:

```
[ '
  "message": "WorldStage Supports Massive 4K Video Mapping at Adobe with Christie Boxer 4K Projectors',
  '
   "message": "Inside Track: Trading Focus on Shares of Adobe Systems Inc. (ADBE)' ]
```

Regex I tried:

```
texts[i].replace(/=\\r/g, "")
```

But it is not working. Could find similar issues at StackOverflow. :(

Comment: Is it a 2 char (``\`` and `r`) combination or just a CR? Try `.replace(/=\r/g, "")`

Comment: Seems to work, but it is still the next line is there. I want it in the same line.

Comment: Then there are other line break symbols. Try `.replace(/=[\r\n]+/g, "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please make it an answer, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex  - `/=\\r/g` - matches all instances of a `=`, `\` and `r`.

You seem to want to remove all instances of `=` and line breaks after the symbol.

Use

```
.replace(/=[\r\n]+/g, "")
```

The `=[\r\n]+` matches a `=`, and `[\r\n]+` matches 1 or more characters defined in the character class, LF (newline symbol, `\n`) and CR (carriage return, `\r`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the carriage return as well, you need at add the newline (`\n`) in your regex.

```
texts[i].replace(/=\\r\n/g, "")
```

See [here](http://regexr.com/3fakm) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Regex:

```
(=\\r\n)
```

```js
const regex = /(=\\r\n)/gm;
const str = `[ '
  "message": "WorldStage Supports Massive 4K Video Mapping at Adobe MAX=\\r
 with Christie Boxer 4K Projectors',
  '
   "message": "Inside Track: Trading Focus on Shares of Adobe Systems In=\\r
c. (ADBE)' ]`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/nbUFtw/2

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```js
var text = '"message": "WorldStage Supports Massive 4K Video Mapping at Adobe MAX=\r with Christie Boxer 4K Projectors';

console.log(text.replace("=", "").replace("\\r", ""));
```